# Cannot find WebBrowser.NavigateToString() method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've heard nice stuff about the `NavigateToString()` C# method, but i can't seem to be able to use it =(
I have a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` in a panel, and when i try to call `NavigateToString()` it says:

> "Error: 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'NavigateToString' and no extension method 'NavigateToString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\Name\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPHPNavigateToString\TestPHPNavigateToString\Form1.cs    TestPHPNavigateToString"

I didn't find anyone with the same issue oO, is there a particular dll i should add a reference to?.

I have vs2010 with .Net FrameWork 4.0, i just reinstalled it just to be sure, but it feels like I'm missing something here =o

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) is available on `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` and not `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx

-> PresentationFramework (in PresentationFramework.dll)

Do you have this reference?